# Tablenotes overlapping with page number

Tags: tablenotes

[image]

```
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,adjustbox,epstopdf,amsmath,
            amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,versionPO}
\usepackage{marginnote,datetime,enumitem,subfigure,rotating,fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref,float}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'table1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
  \centering
   \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}

    \begin{tabular} {llllllr}
    \multicolumn{6}{c} {Table 1: Aid and World Bank, 2000-2014}
    &  \\
      \hline
\cmidrule          & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 & Model 5 &  \\
  \hline
\cmidrule    Chinese Aid (log,t-1) & -0.1424*** & -0.1131*** &       &       &       &  \\
          & (0.0000) & (0.0024) &       &       &       &  \\
    Good Prac.Prin. (Dummy) & 0.6873 & 0.8687 & 0.5552 & 0.7876 & 0.695 &  \\
          & (0.5431) & (0.4505) & (0.6312) & (0.4725) & (0.5214) &  \\
    Avg. Project Size (log) & 0.4172 & 0.6363 & 0.3779 & 0.1865 & 0.1663 &  \\
          & (0.3322) & (0.1126) & (0.3647) & (0.6648) & (0.7027) &  \\
    Avg. Fields & 1.5570*** & 1.5497*** & 1.5732*** & 1.5931*** & 1.6233*** &  \\
          & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) &  \\
    CPI Growth (t-1) & -7.5936 & -7.2876 & -8.2161 & -7.7351 & -8.2952 &  \\
          & (0.3689) & (0.3366) & (0.3299) & (0.3915) & (0.3694) &  \\
    Investments (\% of GDP,t-1) & -0.0668* & -0.0364 & -0.0753* & -0.0507 & -0.0523 &  \\
          & (0.0991) & (0.4197) & (0.0773) & (0.2374) & (0.2503) &  \\
    Reserves (\% of GDP,t-1) & -0.0884*** & -0.0709** & -0.0863*** & -0.0751** & -0.0709** &  \\
          & (0.0033) & (0.0290) & (0.0038) & (0.0234) & (0.0338) &  \\
    GDP per Capita (log,t-1) & 0.7252 & 0.4731 & 0.5588 & 1.0413** & 0.9563** &  \\
          & (0.1020) & (0.3360) & (0.2047) & (0.0207) & (0.0381) &  \\
    GDP Growth (t-1) & -0.106 & -0.0231 & -0.1121 & -0.1347* & -0.1314 &  \\
          & (0.1477) & (0.7351) & (0.1302) & (0.0842) & (0.1045) &  \\
    Gov. Expd. (\% of GDP,t-1) & 0.1448* & 0.1595** & 0.1195 & 0.1132 & 0.0918 &  \\
          & (0.0727) & (0.0416) & (0.1025) & (0.1996) & (0.3118) &  \\
    Ext. Debt (\% of GDP,t-1) & 0.001 & 0.0002 & 0.0016 & 0.0048 & 0.0054 &  \\
          & (0.8687) & (0.9772) & (0.8090) & (0.5287) & (0.4680) &  \\
    FDI (\% of GDP,t-1) & 0.0568 & 0.0392 & 0.0661** & 0.0372 & 0.04  &  \\
          & (0.1127) & (0.2933) & (0.0454) & (0.2928) & (0.2731) &  \\
    Tax Revenue (\% of GDP,t-1) & -0.1260** & -0.1225* & -0.1165** & -0.1287** & -0.1118** &  \\
          & (0.0126) & (0.0512) & (0.0308) & (0.0178) & (0.0393) &  \\
    Monetary Expansion (t-1) & -0.0039 & 0.0116 & -0.0093 & -0.0017 & -0.0111 &  \\
          & (0.8943) & (0.6468) & (0.7528) & (0.9562) & (0.7277) &  \\
    Democracy (t-1) & -0.082 & -0.1152 & -0.0832 & -0.0921 & -0.0915 &  \\
          & (0.2416) & (0.1405) & (0.2304) & (0.1783) & (0.2163) &  \\
    UN Voting Aff. US (t-1) & -9.1826** & 3.2082 & -9.4205** & -7.2536* & -6.8217* &  \\
          & (0.0159) & (0.5746) & (0.0133) & (0.0791) & (0.0993) &  \\
    Trade US (log,t-1) & 0.0751 & -0.1155 & 0.0158 & 0.2594 & 0.2305 &  \\
          & (0.7049) & (0.6675) & (0.9392) & (0.1910) & (0.2529) &  \\
    East Asia \& Pacific (Dummy) &       & 0.5022 &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & (0.3760) &       &       &       &  \\
    Europe \& Central Asia (Dummy) &       & -1.0843** &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & (0.0434) &       &       &       &  \\
    Latin America \& Caribbean (Dummy) &       & 0.5240* &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & (0.0600) &       &       &       &  \\
    Middle East \& South Asia (Dummy) &       & -0.0568 &       &       &       &  \\
          &       & (0.8032) &       &       &       &  \\
    Chinese ODA (log,t-1) &       &       & -0.1763*** &       &       &  \\
          &       &       & (0.0000) &       &       &  \\
    Chinese OOF (log,t-1) &       &       &       & -0.0916** &       &  \\
          &       &       &       & (0.0219) &       &  \\
    Chinese Vague OF (log,t-1) &       &       &       &       & -0.0157 &  \\
          &       &       &       &       & (0.7248) &  \\
\cmidrule    N     & 253   & 253   & 253   & 253   & 253   &  \\
\cmidrule  
  \hline

 \end{adjustbox}
 \label{tab:addlabel}%
  \end{tabular}%
 \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize\smallskip
{Notes: The dependent variable measures the average number of prior actions per World Bank project received by a recipient country i in period t, rounded to the closest integer. Marginal effects at the mean value of the variable are reported. Standard errors are clustered by recipient country. P-values are shown in parentheses. *** p $<$ 0.01, ** p $<$ 0.05, * p $<$ 0.1.}
\end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}

\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ, and which TeX format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else? -- do you use?

Comment: A quick comment: Your table is simply too big for page. Any chance you can either enlarge the text block or show fewer rows in the table? Do you really need to show all rows? Or could you employ a `longtable` and split the table across two pages? Please advise.

Comment: I guess pdfLatex. I am using shareLateX.
Yes, thats the problem, I need to show all rows. However, I can minimize the fontsize.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get what do you mean by enlarging text block?

Comment: Use `longtable` and `threeparttablex` in the place of `threeparttable` to break across pages (note the syntax is slightly different – check in the documentation).

Comment: Its an article and the format is pdfLaTex

Comment: Also: Where might the package `versionPO` be obtained from? Off-topic: the `subfigure` package is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: @Bernard should I use longtable and threeparttablex togeteher?

Comment: @Mico I will complete my code and will re-post it shortly. I am a beginner at LaTex so didn't know how much information related to the code is needed here

Comment: @ImranKhan: Yes, load both.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use a reasonably-sized page block, the table and its legend should fit easily within the available text block. (If you do decide that you could dispense with some of the regressors, the coefficients of the four region dummies would be an obvious place to start.)

Since you don't use any `\tnote` directives, using the `threeparttable` package and its `tablenotes` environment seem like overkill.

Do make an effort, though, to make the table's contents more readable. I'd start by aligning the numbers in the five data columns on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% (I've simplified the preamble to the bare minimum necessary to make the code compile.)
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins suitably
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p!]
\caption{Aid and World Bank, 2000 to 2014} \label{tab:addlabel}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out optimal intercolumn width
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l*{5}{d{2.6}} }
\toprule          
& \mc{Model 1} & \mc{Model 2} & \mc{Model 3} & \mc{Model 4} & \mc{Model 5} \\
\midrule   
Chinese Aid (log, $t{-}1$) & -0.1424^{***} & -0.1131^{***}   \\
                          & (0.0000)   & (0.0024)    \\
Good Prac.Prin.\ (Dummy)  & 0.6873   & 0.8687   & 0.5552   & 0.7876   & 0.695    \\
                          & (0.5431) & (0.4505) & (0.6312) & (0.4725) & (0.5214) \\
Avg.\ Project Size (log)  & 0.4172   & 0.6363   & 0.3779   & 0.1865   & 0.1663   \\
                          & (0.3322) & (0.1126) & (0.3647) & (0.6648) & (0.7027) \\
Avg.\ Fields              & 1.5570^{***}& 1.5497^{***}& 1.5732^{***}& 1.5931^{***}& 1.6233^{***} \\
                          & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) & (0.0000) \\
CPI Growth ($t{-}1$)      & -7.5936  & -7.2876  & -8.2161  & -7.7351  & -8.2952  \\
                          & (0.3689) & (0.3366) & (0.3299) & (0.3915) & (0.3694) \\
Investments (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$) & -0.0668^{*} & -0.0364 & -0.0753^{*} & -0.0507 & -0.0523 \\
                          & (0.0991) & (0.4197) & (0.0773) & (0.2374) & (0.2503) \\
Reserves (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$) & -0.0884^{***} & -0.0709^{**} & -0.0863^{***} & -0.0751^{**} & -0.0709^{**} \\
                          & (0.0033) & (0.0290) & (0.0038) & (0.0234) & (0.0338) \\
GDP per Capita (log, $t{-}1$) & 0.7252 & 0.4731 & 0.5588 & 1.0413^{**} & 0.9563^{**} \\
                          & (0.1020) & (0.3360) & (0.2047) & (0.0207) & (0.0381) \\
GDP Growth ($t{-}1$)      & -0.106   & -0.0231  & -0.1121  & -0.1347^{*}& -0.1314 \\
                          & (0.1477) & (0.7351) & (0.1302) & (0.0842) & (0.1045) \\
Gov.\ Expd.\ (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$) & 0.1448^{*} & 0.1595^{**} & 0.1195 & 0.1132 & 0.0918 \\
                          & (0.0727) & (0.0416) & (0.1025) & (0.1996) & (0.3118) \\
Ext.\ Debt (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$) & 0.001 & 0.0002 & 0.0016 & 0.0048 & 0.0054 \\
                          & (0.8687) & (0.9772) & (0.8090) & (0.5287) & (0.4680) \\
FDI (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$)   & 0.0568 & 0.0392 & 0.0661^{**} & 0.0372 & 0.04  \\
                          & (0.1127) & (0.2933) & (0.0454) & (0.2928) & (0.2731) \\
Tax Revenue (\% of GDP, $t{-}1$) & -0.1260^{**} & -0.1225^{*} & -0.1165^{**} & -0.1287^{**} & -0.1118^{**} \\
                          & (0.0126) & (0.0512) & (0.0308) & (0.0178) & (0.0393) \\
Monetary Expansion ($t{-}1$) & -0.0039 & 0.0116 & -0.0093 & -0.0017 & -0.0111 \\
                          & (0.8943) & (0.6468) & (0.7528) & (0.9562) & (0.7277) \\
Democracy ($t{-}1$)       & -0.082 & -0.1152 & -0.0832 & -0.0921 & -0.0915 \\
                          & (0.2416) & (0.1405) & (0.2304) & (0.1783) & (0.2163) \\
UN Voting Aff.\ US ($t{-}1$) & -9.1826^{**} & 3.2082 & -9.4205^{**} & -7.2536^{*} & -6.8217^{*} \\
                          & (0.0159) & (0.5746) & (0.0133) & (0.0791) & (0.0993) \\
Trade US (log, $t{-}1$)   & 0.0751   & -0.1155  & 0.0158   & 0.2594   & 0.2305 \\
                          & (0.7049) & (0.6675) & (0.9392) & (0.1910) & (0.2529) \\
Chinese ODA (log, $t{-}1$)& & & -0.1763^{***} \\
                          & & & (0.0000) \\
Chinese OOF (log, $t{-}1$)& -0.0916^{**} \\
                          & (0.0219) \\
Chinese Vague OF (log, $t{-}1$) & & -0.0157 \\
                          &       & (0.7248) \\
Region Dummies:\\[0.5ex]
East Asia \& Pacific      &       & 0.5022 \\
                          &       & (0.3760) \\
Europe \& Central Asia    &       & -1.0843^{**} \\
                          &       & (0.0434) \\
Latin America \& Caribbean&       & 0.5240^{*} \\
                          &       & (0.0600) \\
Middle East \& South Asia &       & -0.0568 \\
                          &       & (0.8032) \\
\midrule    
$N$     & \mc{253} & \mc{253} & \mc{253} & \mc{253} & \mc{253} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace  
\end{tabular*}

Notes: The dependent variable measures the average number of prior actions per World Bank project received by a recipient country~$i$ in period~$t$, rounded to the closest integer. Marginal effects at the mean value of the variable are reported. Standard errors are clustered by recipient country. 

$p$-values are shown in parentheses. Significance levels: $^{***}\ p < 0.01$, $^{**}\ p < 0.05$, $^{*} p < 0.1$.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```